# How do I create a json file in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I am using Hugo to build a site made up of lots of venues.

I want to generate a .json file so I can filter the venues by 'day' using some JS e.g. `(window.location.search)` from an appended url e.g. `mysite.com/venues?day=monday`.

How can I get Hugo to generate a json file that I can access with my script?

I have placed the below in a file in `theme/mytheme/layouts/venues/list.json` but nothing is generated in my public folder and i get a 404 in my browser when I go to `http://localhost:55769/venues/list.json` `http://localhost:55769/venues.json` using `hugo server`

```
{
  "churches": [
    {{ range $index, $page := where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "venues" }}
    {
      "title": {{ $page.Title | jsonify }},
      "day": {{ $page.Params.day | jsonify }}
    }
    {{ if not (eq (add $index 1) (len (where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "venues"))) }},{{ end }}
    {{ end }}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the output json format in the config.toml file.

Information is available on [Hugo's page](https://gohugo.io/templates/output-formats/)

You could try something like:

`config.toml`

> [outputs]
> home = [..., "venues"]
> [mediaTypes."application/json"]
>     suffixes = ["json"]
> [outputFormats]
>     [outputFormats.Venues]
>         mediaType = "application/json"
>         baseName = "json/venues" 
>         isPlainText = true

and view the json file at `http://127.0.0.1:1313/json/venues.json`
To retrieve the names and sizes of the images in the `/resources/_gen/images/` folder, I did this:

`/layouts/_default/list.resize.json`

```
    {{ $data := slice  }}
    {{ range readDir "/resources/_gen/images/" }}
        {{ $name := .Name }}
        {{ $size := .Size }}
        {{ $data = $data | append (slice (dict "name" ($name) "size" ($size)))}}
    {{ end }}
    {{ $data | jsonify }}
```

`config.toml`

```
[outputs]
home = ["HTML", "RSS", "Algolia", "resize"]

[mediaTypes."application/json"]
  suffixes = ["json"]

[outputFormats]  
  [outputFormats.Resize]
    mediaType = "application/json"
    baseName = "json/resize" 
    isPlainText = true
```

And I can see the json at `http://127.0.0.1:1313/json/resize.json`